# Increment variable in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have global variable `$scope.posts` in controller Angular JS:
I do increment this variable:

```
$scope.posts = $scope.posts + 1;
```

So my IDE editor underlines this code and tells:

> Value assigned to primitive wil be lost

What is mean and how to fix?

Comment: What do you mean with a global variable?

Comment: `posts` is a primitive (non-object) property of `$scope` in this instance, but being assigned to `$scope` **does not** make the property ***global***.  Your IDE is likely warning you that you are overwriting this property in another controller, but without more code, that can't be confirmed.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs for a more in depth analysis of this and potential solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Init the variable

In your app.js or main Angular module init the variable with this

```
.run(function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.posts;
})
```

Then anywhere you want to increase this use the syntax

```
$scope.posts += 1;
```

It increments the value by one.

## Best Practice

`$rootScope` is probably not what you want. You can share data across your app with a service or a factory. I've made a small Gist to show how this works, check it out [here](https://gist.github.com/joeLloyd/563738e041f3c3d8b16b).